# Confusion about effect of atmospheric pressure on depth at which an object floats

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

The bottom 3.5cm of a plastic block is submerged in water from the lower end of a spring. Why doesn't atmospheric pressure affect the position of the object?

My book says the downward force exerted is cancelled by the upward force of the water on the object. How is that possible if the downward force is on the water and the upward force on the object? Please explain with a diagram if possible. I'm very confused.

Comment: Pressure in a fluid always is the same in every direction, and the pressure at the interface between two different fluids (e.g., air and water) must be the same in both of them.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't? And do you think it's large enough to consider compared to other things. You don't tell the size of the block, the stretch of the spring ( is it totally relaxed), does the block float, how much of the block is in the air. Also, the atmospheric pressure *is*  net downward on the block. I think your book is wrong because the fluid force depends on the volume of the block in each regime (above versus below water) and the density of each regime (air versus water). The buoyant force of the water is MUCH larger than what the air is doing.

Comment: Just to be sure that responders are answering the question that you asked, what do you expect atmospheric pressure to do to the partially submerged plastic block, and how is this different from what the text books say?

Answer (score 0):

> My book says the downward force exerted is cancelled by the upward force of the water on the object. How is that possible if the downward force is on the water and the upward force on the object?

No the weight of the body acts **on the object** itself at all times and the water applies a buoyant force in the opposite direction **on the body**
This buoyant force balances the net downward force acting on the body.[image: free body diagram]
Now you see by the free body diagram all the forces are acting **on the body**
$$Net  downward force=mg-Kx$$
Where $mg$ is it's weight and $kx$ is spring force both acting **on the body**.
It is balanced by the buoyant force(acting on the body)as the body is in equilibrium,
$$Buoyant force=mg-kx$$ and the forces are balanced

> Why doesn't atmospheric pressure affect the position of the object?

Now as far as considering atmospheric pressure is concerned it acts equally on the body and the water so it is neglected most of the times.The water's reaction pair to the atmospheric pressure and the atmospheric pressure on the block in opposite directions cancel each other and are not considered in the equation

Comment: You haven't answered the question. OP is asking about the effect of the atmospheric pressure.

Comment: I did in the end of the answer..